# What is the difference between lemmatization vs stemming?

Tags: nlp, nltk, lemmatization

When do I use each ?

Also...is the NLTK lemmatization dependent upon Parts of Speech?
Wouldn't it be more accurate if it was?

Comment: This is way over my head, but why is there a python tag?

Comment: @jimmy: tagged python b/c it's talking about the python nltk library

Comment: Here's a great article that answers this exact [question](http://www.ideaeng.com/tabId/98/itemId/180/Whats-the-Difference-Between-Stemming-and-Lemmati.aspx)

Comment: See also: [Stemmers vs Lemmatizers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317418)

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Short and dense: http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html

> The goal of both stemming and lemmatization is to reduce inflectional forms and sometimes derivationally related forms of a word to a common base form.
>
> However, the two words differ in their flavor. Stemming usually refers to a crude heuristic process that chops off the ends of words in the hope of achieving this goal correctly most of the time, and often includes the removal of derivational affixes. Lemmatization usually refers to doing things properly with the use of a vocabulary and morphological analysis of words, normally aiming to remove inflectional endings only and to return the base or dictionary form of a word, which is known as the lemma .

From the NLTK docs:

> Lemmatization and stemming are special cases of normalization. They identify a canonical representative for a set of related word forms.

Comment: curious to learn what the average lemmatization length tell us about a doc?

Comment: That doesn't fully answer the question. You don't explain when to use which. Both can serve for normalization but often which one you choose is a trade-off between precision and speed.

Comment: @dzieciou, thanks for the input - you may be able to edit the answer; and I will try to add some more context as well.

Answer (score 108):

> **Lemmatisation** is closely related to **stemming**. The difference is that a
>   stemmer operates on a single word without knowledge of the context,
>   and therefore cannot discriminate between words which have different
>   meanings depending on part of speech. However, stemmers are typically
>   easier to implement and run faster, and the reduced accuracy may not
>   matter for some applications.
>
> For instance:
>
> 1. The word "better" has "good" as its lemma. This link is missed by
>      stemming, as it requires a dictionary look-up.
> 2. The word "walk" is the base form for word "walking", and hence this
>      is matched in both stemming and lemmatisation.
> 3. The word "meeting" can be either the base form of a noun or a form
>      of a verb ("to meet") depending on the context, e.g., "in our last
>      meeting" or "We are meeting again tomorrow". Unlike stemming,
>      lemmatisation can in principle select the appropriate lemma
>      depending on the context.

*Source*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation

Comment: Well, there are dictionary-based stemmers that would be able to normalize better to good, e.g., http://www.cs.put.poznan.pl/dweiss/xml/projects/lametyzator/index.xml?lang=en

Answer (score 45):

**Stemming** just removes or stems the last few characters of a word, often leading to incorrect meanings and spelling. **Lemmatization** considers the context and converts the word to its meaningful base form, which is called Lemma. Sometimes, the same word can have multiple different Lemmas. We should identify the Part of Speech (POS) tag for the word in that specific context.  Here are the examples to illustrate all the differences and use cases:

1. If you lemmatize the word '**Caring**', it would return '**Care**'. If you stem, it would return '**Car**' and this is erroneous.
2. If you lemmatize the word '**Stripes**' in **verb** context, it would return '**Strip**'. If you lemmatize it in **noun** context, it would return '**Stripe**'. If you just stem it, it would just return '**Strip**'.
3. You would get same results whether you lemmatize or stem words such as **walking, running, swimming**... to **walk, run, swim** etc.
4. Lemmatization is computationally expensive since it involves look-up tables and what not. If you have large dataset and performance is an issue, go with Stemming. Remember you can also add your own rules to Stemming. If accuracy is paramount and dataset isn't humongous, go with Lemmatization.

Comment: Stemming the word "Stemming" and "Swimming" would these give "stemm" & "swimm" or "stem" & "swim"

Answer (score 32):

There are two aspects to show their differences:

1. A **stemmer** will return the stem of a word, which needn't be identical to the morphological root of the word. It usually sufficient that related words map to the same stem,even if the stem is not in itself a valid root, while in **lemmatisation**, it will return the dictionary form of a word, which must be a valid word.
2. In **lemmatisation**, the part of speech of a word should be first determined and the normalisation rules will be different for different part of speech, while the **stemmer** operates on a single word without knowledge of the context, and therefore cannot discriminate between words which have different meanings depending on part of speech.

Reference http://textminingonline.com/dive-into-nltk-part-iv-stemming-and-lemmatization

Answer (score 22):

The purpose of both stemming and lemmatization is to reduce morphological variation. This is in contrast to the the more general "term conflation" procedures, which may also address lexico-semantic, syntactic, or orthographic variations.

The real difference between stemming and lemmatization is threefold:

1. Stemming reduces word-forms to (pseudo)stems, whereas lemmatization reduces the word-forms to linguistically valid lemmas. This difference is apparent in languages with more complex morphology, but may be irrelevant for many IR applications;
2. Lemmatization deals only with inflectional variance, whereas stemming may also deal with derivational variance;
3. In terms of implementation, lemmatization is usually more sophisticated (especially for morphologically complex languages) and usually requires some sort of lexica. Satisfatory stemming, on the other hand, can be achieved with rather simple rule-based approaches.

Lemmatization may also be backed up by a part-of-speech tagger in order to disambiguate homonyms.

Answer (score 16):

As MYYN pointed out, stemming is the process of removing inflectional and sometimes derivational affixes to a base form that all of the original words are probably related to.  Lemmatization is concerned with obtaining the single word that allows you to group together a bunch of inflected forms.  This is harder than stemming because it requires taking the context into account (and thus the meaning of the word), while stemming ignores context.

As for when you would use one or the other, it's a matter of how much your application depends on getting the meaning of a word in context correct.  If you're doing machine translation, you probably want lemmatization to avoid mistranslating a word.  If you're doing information retrieval over a billion documents with 99% of your queries ranging from 1-3 words, you can settle for stemming.

As for NLTK, the WordNetLemmatizer does use the part of speech, though you have to provide it (otherwise it defaults to nouns).  Passing it "dove" and "v" yields "dive" while "dove" and "n" yields "dove".

Answer (score 14):

An example-driven explanation on the differenes between lemmatization and stemming:

**Lemmatization** handles **matching “car” to “cars” along
with matching “car” to “automobile”.**

**Stemming** handles **matching “car” to “cars”** .

> Lemmatization implies a broader scope of fuzzy word matching that is
>   still handled by the same subsystems.  It implies certain techniques
>   for low level processing within the engine, and may also reflect an
>   engineering preference for terminology.
>
> [...] Taking FAST as an example,
>   their lemmatization engine handles not only basic word variations like
>   singular vs. plural, but also thesaurus operators like having “hot”
>   match “warm”.
>
> This is not to say that other engines don’t handle synonyms, of course
>   they do, but the low level implementation may be in a different
>   subsystem than those that handle base stemming.

http://www.ideaeng.com/stemming-lemmatization-0601

Answer (score 9):

Stemming is the process of removing the last few characters of a given word, to obtain a shorter form, even if that form doesn't have any meaning.

Examples,

```
"beautiful" -> "beauti"
"corpora" -> "corpora"
```

[image: More examples of stemming]

Stemming can be done very quickly.

Lemmatization on the other hand, is the process of converting the given word into it's base form according to the dictionary meaning of the word.

Examples,

```
"beautiful" -> "beauty"
"corpora" -> "corpus"
```

[image: More examples of lemmatization]

Lemmatization takes more time than stemming.

Answer (score 4):

I think Stemming is a rough hack that people use to get all the different forms of the same word down to a base form which needs not be a legit word on its own.
Something like the Porter Stemmer can use simple regexes to eliminate common word suffixes.

Lemmatization brings a word down to its actual base form which, in the case of irregular verbs, might look nothing like the input word.
Something like Morpha which uses FSTs to bring nouns and verbs to their base form.

Comment: I think that the Porter Stemmer is implemented without recourse to Regular Expressions, because many older languages don't have them, but otherwise you've got the right idea.

Answer (score 2):

Huang et al. describes the Stemming and Lemmatization as the following. The selection depends upon the problem and computational resource availability.

> Stemming identifies the common root form of a word by removing or replacing word suffixes (e.g. “flooding” is stemmed as “flood”), while lemmatization identifies the inflected forms of a word and returns its base form (e.g. “better” is lemmatized as “good”).

Huang, X., Li, Z., Wang, C., & Ning, H. (2020). Identifying disaster related social media for rapid response: a visual-textual fused CNN architecture. International Journal of Digital Earth, 13(9), 1017–1039. https://doi.org/10.1080/17538947.2019.1633425

Answer (score 1):

Stemming and Lemmatization both generate the foundation sort of the inflected words and therefore the only difference is that stem may not be an actual word whereas, lemma is an actual language word.

Stemming follows an algorithm with steps to perform on the words which makes it faster. Whereas, in lemmatization, you used a corpus also to supply lemma which makes it slower than stemming. you furthermore might had to define a parts-of-speech to get the proper lemma.

The above points show that if speed is concentrated then stemming should be used since lemmatizers scan a corpus which consumes time and processing. It depends on the problem you’re working on that decides if stemmers should be used or lemmatizers.
for more info visit the link:
https://towardsdatascience.com/stemming-vs-lemmatization-2daddabcb221

Answer (score 1):

Stemming:
"Caring" stemmed to "car" (incorrect word) or "better" stemmed to "bet" (confuses with the gambling term).
Lemmatization:
"Caring" lemmatized to "care" (correct and maintains meaning) and "better" lemmatized to "good" (correct and identifies the base form).

Answer (score 0):

**Stemming**
is the process of producing morphological variants of a root/base word. Stemming programs are commonly referred to as stemming algorithms or stemmers.
Often when searching text for a certain keyword, it helps if the search returns variations of the word.
For instance, searching for “boat” might also return “boats” and “boating”. Here, “boat” would be the stem for [boat, boater, boating, boats].

**Lemmatization**
looks beyond word reduction and considers a language’s full vocabulary to apply a morphological analysis to words. The lemma of ‘was’ is ‘be’ and the lemma of ‘mice’ is ‘mouse’.

I did refer this link,
https://towardsdatascience.com/stemming-vs-lemmatization-2daddabcb221

Answer (score 0):

In short, the difference between these algorithms is that only [lemmatization](https://databasecamp.de/en/data/stemming-lemmatization) includes the meaning of the word in the evaluation. In [stemming](https://databasecamp.de/en/data/stemming-lemmatization), only a certain number of letters are cut off from the end of the word to obtain a word stem. The meaning of the word does not play a role in it.

Answer (score 0):

In short:

> **Lemmatization**: uses context to transform words to their
> dictionary(base) form also known as Lemma

> **Stemming**: uses the stem of the word, most of the time removing derivational affixes.

[source](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-nlp-part-2-difference-between-lemmatisation-and-stemming-3789be1c55bc)