# Morphology:Tool to get the root word and suffix for a given english word

Tags: nlp, nltk, wordnet, stemming, morphological-analysis

I am trying to do morph analysis in POS tagging.

Is there any tool (which I can call from within a python or java script) which returns the Root form and its suffix , when we call it by passing  an English word as parameter.

### For example:

if I give input:'liked' , I want to get output:like,ed

To get the root form for a given english word, I tried to use porter stemmer and snowball stemmer (inside a python script) but It does not give the valid root word always, since it just strips off the suffix.

```
from nltk.stem.porter import *
porter_stemmer = PorterStemmer()
print(porter_stemmer.stem("ladies"))
print(porter_stemmer.stem("went"))
```

### output

```
ladi   
went
```

for example:
I gave input as 'ladies'
but it return 'ladi' as root form , which is not even an English word.

Sometimes stemmers just return the input word as it is.
for example,
I gave input 'went' and these stemmers return 'went' as root form instead of 'go'.

Please suggest which tool I can use, to get the root form and suffix.

Comment: You don't want a "stemmer", you want morphological analysis. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317418/stemmers-vs-lemmatizers

Answer (score 4):

```
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
WNL = WordNetLemmatizer()
WNL.lemmatize('ladies')
WNL.lemmatize('went')
```

(I'm trying to find something else to say here, but I think that code is self-explanatory?)

Comment: perhaps you could include the output of your commands