# Porter Stemming of fried

Tags: nlp, nltk, stemming, porter-stemmer

Why does the porter stemming algorithm online at

http://text-processing.com/demo/stem/

stem `fried` to `fri` and not `fry`?

I can't recall any words ending with `ied` past tense in English that have a nominative form ending with `i`.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A stem as returned by Porter Stemmer is not necessarily the base form of a verb, or a valid word at all. If you're looking for that, you need to look for a lemmatizer instead.

Comment: Great! Could someone give a link to some algorithm (paper or code) describing how the stemmer and lemmatizer are used in conjunction to, for instance, convert `friedness` to `fry`? Does the lemmatizer always operate on the output of the stemming algorithm or does it need both the original and stemmed version of the word?

Comment: Not always. For example, the lemma of most forms of "be"--"is", "was", "were", "are"--can't be determined from the stem. Stemming is simpler but error prone. In certain applications, though, that's acceptable. A lemmatizer may also use a stemmer as a fall-back.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, a stemmer is not a lemmatizer, see also [Stemmers vs Lemmatizers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317418/stemmers-vs-lemmatizers):

```
>>> from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer, WordNetLemmatizer
>>> porter = PorterStemmer()
>>> wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
>>> fried = 'fried'
>>> porter.stem(fried)
u'fri'
>>> wnl.lemmatize(fried)
'fried'
```

Next, a lemmatizer is Part-Of-Speech (POS) sensitive:

```
>>> wnl.lemmatize(fried, pos='v')
u'fry'
```