# Is there a way to correctly remove the tense or plural from a word?

Tags: python, nltk

Is it possible to to change words like running, helping, cooks, finds and happily into run, help, cook, find and happy using nltk?

Comment: I've used the stemming filter in whoosh (see more at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Whoosh/2.6.0)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Porter Stemming of fried](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659179/porter-stemming-of-fried)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are some stemming algorithms implemented in `nltk`. It looks like `Lancaster` stemming algorithm will work for you.

```
>>> from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
>>> st = LancasterStemmer()
>>> st.stem('happily')
'happy'
>>> st.stem('cooks')
'cook'
>>> st.stem('helping')
'help'
>>> st.stem('running')
'run'
>>> st.stem('finds')
'find'
```

Comment: (beware cases where it works against you)

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
>>> wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()

>>> ls = ['running', 'helping', 'cooks', 'finds']
>>> [wnl.lemmatize(i) for i in ls]
['running', 'helping', u'cook', u'find']

>>> ls = [('running', 'v'), ('helping', 'v'), ('cooks', 'v'), ('finds','v')]
>>> [wnl.lemmatize(word, pos) for word, pos in ls]
[u'run', u'help', u'cook', u'find']

>>> ls = [('running', 'n'), ('helping', 'n'), ('cooks', 'n'), ('finds','n')]
>>> [wnl.lemmatize(word, pos) for word, pos in ls]
['running', 'helping', u'cook', u'find']
```

See [Porter Stemming of fried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659179/porter-stemming-of-fried)

Comment: This should be marked as "correct". "lemmatize" is more accurate then "LancasterStemmer". Sine for the word "wires", "LancasterStemmer" returns "wir" and "leminatize" return the correct one "wire".