# Extract main word from its descendants with python

Tags: python, nltk

Would like to know if there is a way to extract the main word out of descendants,

ex:

```
recruitment -> recruit
recruiter -> recruit
recruited -> recruit
```

I got the last one using wordnet lemmatizer, like this:

```
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
lmtzr = WordNetLemmatizer()
lmtzr.lemmatize('recruited', 'v')
```

can't seem to find a solution for the others, is there a library for that or should I code a function.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317418/stemmers-vs-lemmatizers

Comment: There are some good morphological analyzers available online like Morfessor http://www.cis.hut.fi/projects/morpho/index.shtml.

Comment: Try this http://asr.aalto.fi/morfessordemo/.

Comment: interesting tool. Not really what I am looking for though. I think I'll develop something on my own

Answer (score 2):

I think you are talking about `stemming` :

http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html

> A processing interface for removing morphological affixes from words. This process is known as stemming.

```
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
st = LancasterStemmer()
st.stem('recruitment')
st.stem('recruiter')
st.stem('recruited')
```

Comment: No I know stemming, but I actually need the real english word. For example stemming `conclusion` with snowball returns `conclus` which is not what I desire

Comment: Ok I understand. I don't know if there is something like this but you could check this link : https://github.com/vinta/awesome-python#text-processing

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, lancaster was a good start, `conclusion` became `conclud` which then I passed it to `en.suggest('conclud')` which gave `conclude` but didn't work for `revision` which became `revid`

Answer (score 2):

Try LancasterStemmer from nltk

```
import nltk 
lancaster = nltk.LancasterStemmer()

print lancaster.stem("recruitment")
print lancaster.stem("recruiter")
print lancaster.stem("recruited")
```