# Given two words, find whether they are in the same synset

Tags: python, nltk

am fairly new to nltk. I am trying to find out a solution to the 
problem I am currently working on:

- Given two words w1 and w2 is there a way to find out whether they belong to the same sysnet in the Wordnet database?
- Also is it possible to find the list of sysnets that contain a given word?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also is it possible to find the list of sysnets that contain a given
>   word?

**Yes**:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> auto, car = 'auto', 'car'
>>> wn.synsets(auto)
[Synset('car.n.01')]
>>> wn.synsets(car)
[Synset('car.n.01'), Synset('car.n.02'), Synset('car.n.03'), Synset('car.n.04'), Synset('cable_car.n.01')]
```

If we look at lemmas in every synset from `wn.synsets(car)`, we'll find "car" exist as one of the lemma:

```
>>> for ss in wn.synsets(car):
...     assert 'car' in ss.lemma_names()
... 
>>> for ss in wn.synsets(car):
...     print 'car' in ss.lemma_names(), ss.lemma_names()
... 
True [u'car', u'auto', u'automobile', u'machine', u'motorcar']
True [u'car', u'railcar', u'railway_car', u'railroad_car']
True [u'car', u'gondola']
True [u'car', u'elevator_car']
True [u'cable_car', u'car']
```

**Note:** A lemma is not exactly a surface word, see [Stemmers vs Lemmatizers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317418/stemmers-vs-lemmatizers), also, you might find this helpful https://github.com/alvations/pywsd/blob/master/pywsd/utils.py#L66 (Disclaimer: Shameless plug)

> Given two words w1 and w2 is there a way to find out whether they
>   belong to the same sysnet in the Wordnet database?

**Yes**:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> auto, car = 'auto', 'car'
>>> wn.synsets(auto)
[Synset('car.n.01')]
>>> wn.synsets(car)
[Synset('car.n.01'), Synset('car.n.02'), Synset('car.n.03'), Synset('car.n.04'), Synset('cable_car.n.01')]
>>> auto_ss = set(wn.synsets(auto))
>>> car_ss = set(wn.synsets(car))
>>> car_ss.intersection(auto_ss)
set([Synset('car.n.01')])
```