# How to slice different verb tenses word ending with -ed,-ing in a list?

Tags: python, nltk

So here is the sample list:
**[work,worked,working,play,works,lotus]**

I want to slice the -ed,-ing,-s form of work,the result should be like this:
 **[work,play,lotus]**
So,how can i achieve that with pure python code since the NLTK approach seemed to be inaccurate?

Comment: It's called stemming, and you need a language processing library to do it, not pure python. Please show the NLTK code

Comment: Which library you have used in nltk ? You can use PorterStemmer() , It will convert the word to its root form.

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647400/what-is-the-best-stemming-method-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code:

Code:

```
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
stemmer = PorterStemmer()

List = ['work','worked','working','play']
List = [stemmer.stem(token) for token in List]
List1=[]
for token in List:
    if token not in List1:
        List1.append(token)
```

Output:

```
['work', 'play']
```

Comment: It's so inaccurate,how can i simply seperate working from work and slice out the "ing" without  slicing out unwanted words like "sing".

Comment: What is inaccurate in this?

Comment: what if the list change to["bring","sing","bringing"]

Comment: It will be ['bring', 'sing', 'bring'] first try it.

Answer (score 1):

In python, you can use filter to remove values which ends with `ing` or `ed`.

```
your_list = ['work', 'worked', 'working', 'play']
print filter(lambda i: not i.endswith(('ing', 'ed')), your_list)
```

it returns a list.

```
['work', 'play']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
List = ['work','worked','working','play']

[item for item in List if not item.endswith(("ed", "ing"))]
```

Comment: It will slice the unwanted words like "bring"or "sing" out of the list