# How to use Stemmer or Lemmatizer to stem specific word

Tags: java, python, nlp, stemming, lemmatization

I am currently trying to stem a big corpus(aprox. 800k sentences). I've managed to stem only the basic one. The problem now is that I want to stem only a specific word for example this method only applies if the lemma is a substring of the original word. For instance, the suffix for the word apples are apple and 's'. But if not a substring, it will not split it like the word teeth into tooth.

I've also read about lemmatizer WordNet, where we can add a parameter for pos such as verb, noun or adjective. Is there a way that I can apply the method above?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can look for previous questions [what-is-the-best-stemming-method-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647400/what-is-the-best-stemming-method-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complete example here -

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from difflib import get_close_matches as gcm
from itertools import chain
from nltk.stem.porter import *

texts = [ " apples are good. My teeth will fall out.",
          " roses are red. cars are great to have"]

lmtzr = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()
stemmer = PorterStemmer()

for text in texts:
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text) # should sent tokenize it first
    token_lemma = [ lmtzr.lemmatize(token) for token in tokens ] # take your pick here between lemmatizer and wordnet synset.
    wn_lemma = [ gcm(word, list(set(list(chain(*[i.lemma_names() for i in wordnet.synsets(word)]))))) for word in tokens ]
    #print(wn_lemma) # works for unconventional words like 'teeth' --> tooth. You might want to take a closer look
    tokens_final = [ stemmer.stem(tokens[i]) if len(tokens[i]) > len(token_lemma[i]) else token_lemma[i] for i in range(len(tokens)) ]
    print(tokens_final)
```

**Output**

```
['appl', 'are', 'good', '.', 'My', 'teeth', 'will', 'fall', 'out', '.']
['rose', 'are', 'red', '.', 'car', 'are', 'great', 'to', 'have']
```

**Explanation**

Notice `stemmer.stem(tokens[i]) if len(tokens[i]) > len(token_lemma[i]) else token_lemma[i]` this is where the magic happens. If the lemmatized word is a subset of the main word, then the word gets stemmed, otherwise it just remains lemmatized.

**Note**

The lemmatization that you are attempting has some edge cases. `WordnetLemmatizer` is not smart enough to handle exceptional cases like 'teeth' --> 'tooth'. In those cases you would want to take a look at `Wordnet.synset` which might come in handy.

I have included a small case in the comments for your investigation.

Comment: is it possible to count the number of verbs in a sentence using WornetLemmatizer?

Comment: Nope. You will have to pos tag the sentences first and then search for words tagged as verb. Lemmatizers have nothing to do with grammatical tags

Comment: Instead of removing the suffix, can it be separated instead, for example: apples becomes apple -s , perform -ed ?