# SnowballStemmer("english") is not working for a list of words

Tags: python, nltk, stemming, porter-stemmer, snowball-stemmer

I am trying to learn Stemming in NLTK and while I try to stem words with SnowballStemmer it has stuck with PorterStemmer.

Although when I try to stem one single word it works properly but when I try to stem a list of words, it stems with PorterStemmer.

I have created a new list named "singles" to add all the stem words into that list but the result is not what I am looking for.

As you can see, when I used "generously", everything looks just fine, but when I try to print "singles" which is supposed to include all the stem words of "plurals" list, I get the stem words with PorterStemmer.

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer

plurals = ['caresses', 'flies', 'dies', 'mules', 'denied','died', 'agreed', 'owned', 'humbled', 'sized','meeting', 'stating', 'siezing', 'itemization','sensational', 'traditional', 'reference', 'colonizer','plotted']
stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")
singles = [stemmer.stem(plural) for plural in plurals]

print(SnowballStemmer("english").stem("generously"))
print(" ".join(singles))
```

The issue is that I don't what to stem "generously", I want to stem the list named "plurals". I just added "generously" to show that it works fine for one word but not for a list.

I would really appreciate it if you help me understand what I am missing.

Comment: The snowball stemmer returns "generous" whereas the porter stemmer  return "gener". It hasn't stuck with the `PorterStemmer` since the word stem returned for "generously" is different for both

Comment: the issue is that I don't what to stem "generously", I want to stem the list named "plurals". I just added "generously" to show that it works fine for one word but not for a list.

Comment: Can you try including "generously" in the list and check if it works?

Comment: it has stemmed it correctly. does that mean that even SnowballStemmer("english") does not work perfectly for all english words?

Comment: Those are the proper word stems from using the [snowball stemming algorithm](https://snowballstem.org/)

Comment: Is there any way to make it work without loosing the meaning of the word?

Comment: You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24663617). As the answer suggests, you may find a better result using the wordnet lemmatizer

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317418/stemmers-vs-lemmatizers