# Can I get a word from its radical after stemming?

Tags: python, nltk, stemming

I stemmed a text and got radicals and now I want to have an output that has a meaning. I know that a radical has many words that can be created from, I just need one. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try lemmatization rather than stemming. This process attempts to generate a canonical "dictionary word" rather than a radical for each input. See [What is the difference between lemmatization vs stemming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787110/what-is-the-difference-between-lemmatization-vs-stemming).

Otherwise, you could use a dict to keep track of the words that mapped to each stem. (This code stores a set of words, but you could modify it to just record a single word per stem.)

```
from collections import defaultdict

def get_stem_dict(words, stemmer):
    stem_to_words = defaultdict(set)
    for word in words:
        stem = stemmer.stem(word)
        stem_to_words[stem].add(word)
    return stem_to_words
```

Then you could use the dict to look up an example word for a given stem:

```
def get_example(stem_to_words, stem):
    return next(iter(stem_to_words[stem]))
```

Comment: Oh this is great thanks for your help !